# Unable to call a parent method using the child method trigger

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

**I am unable to execute the method using the child trigger in one case of the angular app.** 
I have placed a console log both in the parent and the child method, **only the child method is being called at all.** The parent has a paramater of a type object so I have tried to remove the paramater just to see if the function can be called at all the **problem seems to me to be located in** `(myChildMethod)="myParentMethod()"` yet I do not know why in another instance of the app I have managed to do this so I tried to copy it and check for any differences yet I the ones I saw such as spacing seem irrelevent. 
**I have marked the parts of the code that I believe are relevent to the issue as "Important"** but I have posted the entire components in case the issue lies somewhere where I didn't know I should look.

**The child shopping-edit-component HTML is :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-5 form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label> 
                    <input type="text" 
                    id="name" 
                    class="form-control"
                    #nameInput
                    >
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 form-group">
                    <label for="amount">amount</label>
                    <input type="number" 
                    id="amount" 
                    class="form-control"
                    #amountInput>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                    <button class="btn btn-success"
                        type="button"
                        (click)="addNew()">Add</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" 
                    type="button">Delete</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The child shopping-edit-component TS is :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from "../../shared/ingredient.model"

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-edit.component.css']
})  
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('nameInput', {static: false}) nameInputRef: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('amountInput', {static: false}) amountInputRef: ElementRef;

  @Output() emitIngredient = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>(); 
  // IMPORTANT 
  addNew(nameEl: ElementRef, amountEl:  ElementRef){
    console.log("addNew");
    const newIngredient = new Ingredient(
       this.nameInputRef.nativeElement.value,
       this.amountInputRef.nativeElement.value
    );

        this.emitIngredient.emit(newIngredient);
  }

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

**The parent shopping-list-component html is :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <!-- IMPORTANT -->
        <app-shopping-edit  (addNew)= "addNewIngredient($event)"></app-shopping-edit>
        <hr>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <a class="list-group-item" 
            style="cursor: pointer"
            *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
            {{ ingredient.name }} , {{ ingredient.amount}}  
        </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the parent shopping-list-component ts is :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredient.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-list',
  templateUrl: './shopping-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-list.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {

  ingredients: Ingredient[] = [
    new Ingredient('Apples', 5),
    new Ingredient('Potato', 3)

  ];
  // IMPORTANT
  addNewIngredient(newIngredient: Ingredient){
    console.log("addNewIngredient");
    this.ingredients.push(newIngredient);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have succeed in one case to pass data between a child and the parent. 
Child Header Component Html. All the code bellow works to the working example of the app.

```
    <div class="navbar-default">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li (click)="onRecipeSelected('recipe')"><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
                <li (click)="onListSelected('list')"><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
            </ul> 
</div>

Child Header Component Ts
```

import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',
    templateUrl: "./header.component.html"
})
export class HeaderComponent {

```
    @Output() featureSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

    onRecipeSelected(feature: string){

        this.featureSelected.emit(feature);
    }

    onListSelected(feature: string){
        this.featureSelected.emit(feature)
    }

}
```

Parent App Component HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-mid-12">
          <app-recipes 
          *ngIf="loadedFeature === 'recipe'"></app-recipes>
          <app-shopping-list 
          *ngIf="loadedFeature === 'list'"></app-shopping-list>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Parent App Component Ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'RecipeApp';
  value = 10;



   loadedFeature = "recipe";

   onNavigate(feature: string){

     this.loadedFeature = feature;
   }
 }
```

This works fine. The parent component is being called the value being passed.

**The app-module file is :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { RecipeItemComponent } from './recipes/recipe-list/recipe-item/recipe-item.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';
import { ShoppingEditComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-edit/shopping-edit.component';
import { RecipeDetailComponent } from './recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.component';
import { HighlighterDirective } from './highlighter/highlighter.directive';
import { UnlessDirective } from './highlighter/unless.directive';
import { DropdownDirective } from './shared/dropdown.directive';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';  

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    ShoppingListComponent,
    ShoppingEditComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    HighlighterDirective,
    UnlessDirective,
    DropdownDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You forgot the minimal part of [mcve]

Comment: Yeah I know originally I just wrote the short segment of the code which I thought was relevant but I am just not too sure where the problem is I have been trying to solve this since yesterday and if I knew where the problem was I would have probably solved it

Comment: "<app-shopping-edit  (emitIngredient)= "addNewIngredient($event)"></app-shopping-edit>" - Your child component used statement like this, Please check Parent and child component interaction - https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: That's it I've been calling the function of the child method instead of the emitted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add your event in your HTML which contains your emitted value from the child component

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
    <app-shopping-edit  (addNew)= "addNewIngredient($event)"></app-shopping-edit>
    <hr>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <a class="list-group-item" 
        style="cursor: pointer"
        *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        {{ ingredient.name }} , {{ ingredient.amount}}  
    </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I just forgot to update it. But that was the way it was originally and I removed the ($event) when i removed all the parameters from the function to see if the parameters were just not being read